# How to loop through nested json objects in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, loops

I have been trying to retrieve Postal_code
from the following google API but unable to loop through the JSON array

This is the function for parsing JSON

```
func parseJson(Json:Data)  {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MapModel.self, from: Json)
        let postal_code = decodedData.results[0].address_components[0].long_name

        print(postal_code)

    } catch {                
        print(error)
        return   
    }             
}
```

this is the model:

```
struct MapModel: Decodable { 
    let results : [Result] 
    let status: String 
    let plus_code : compoundCode 
} 

struct compoundCode: Decodable { 
    let compound_code: String 
} 

struct Result: Decodable { 
    let address_components:[address_components] 
} 

struct address_components: Decodable { 
    let long_name : Int 
}
```

This the JSON through API

```
{  
   "plus_code":{  
      "compound_code":"5WXX+7J Thane, Maharashtra, India",
      "global_code":"7JFJ5WXX+7J"
   },
   "results":[  
      {  
         "address_components":[  
            {  
               "long_name":"400604",
               "short_name":"400604",
               "types":[  
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Thane",
               "short_name":"Thane",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This is the model for the following ...........                                                                             
   struct MapModel :Decodable{
    let results : [Result]
    let status: String
    let plus_code : compoundCode
    
}

struct compoundCode:Decodable {
    let compound_code: String
}
struct Result :Decodable {
    let address_components:[address_components]
}
struct address_components : Decodable{
    let  long_name : Int
    
}

Comment: Add that information to your question, code in comments is hard to read. And exactly what is a pin code in this context, what field are you trying to access?

Comment: I meant postal code...i just need the dictionary with postal code...my bad

Comment: @RajatKotian Please fix your question by clicking on the edit button right under the tags.

Comment: Done!! Now how can i access the long_name with postal code and not the name of the city

Comment: Your code still says `pincode` and you didn't add the `MapModel` code.

Comment: It is in comments...stackoverflow was not allowing me to add more code @koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer for the following question...the problem was there multiple values for the key "long_name" for the give JSON objects..the solution for this is to loop through the "address_components" and look for the unique values for the "type" key in the JSON object..for Example in this case the key "long_name " had two values "thane" and "400604" but the unique key is the types that can be used to differentiate between those

This is the syntax for the folloing problem!!

```
func parseJson(Json:Data)  
      {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do{
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MapModel.self, from: Json)

            for item in decodedData.results[0].address_components{
                if item.types[0] == "postal_code"{
                    print(item.long_name)
                }
            }
        }

        catch{

            print(error)
            return 

        }
    }
```